# I have accidentally removed efi partition from my system, how can I return it back

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

There is lot of *"simmilar"* questions, but I haven't seen any which would solved my problem, I were trying to repair external disk, and when I wanted to format it, it unmounted itself so I accidentlly removed my efi from /dev/sda1/, I have tried to search for solution for how to take this back, but I screwed thing even further, at this moment my disk includes second ubuntu instance and uses its efi, I've tried to play a little with grub, but what I really want is to remove this new instance of ubuntu after I repair efi

I gues it's compliceted explanation so to tell it simply - how can I replace efi partition with new one created in os, so I can remove that one?

Comment: I confused on what you are creating or removing? But you have to have an ESP - efi system partition. Then if you just reinstall grub it will add back the files in the ESP and new entry in UEFI. But if default mount of ESP in fstab is not the one you want then it will update the wrong one. Probably easier then to use Boot-Repair, but you can manually specify partition. Boot-Repair will not create an ESP, use gparted. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: well... finally I decided, way that is described in that link doesn't work same (I use ubuntu server 16.10, at part where I should install grub it fails) so I just installed it at the end of disk - it's just 2 GB at HDD (propably could go with less), so almost no data, if you know any way how to change filesystem from which grub choses options, I would be grateful (propably step by step in terminal), but this is enough, thanks for your help

Comment: If 16.10, you probably will have issues. It is not supported anymore. Use a supported version of Ubuntu. Most with servers only use LTS versions to get the 5 years of life. Suggest you use 20.04. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: I don't use it as os, I only need small os (propably has to be debian) with grub, so I can run my ubuntu 20.04 with all data